# Express $2.7\overline2$ as an infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Express $2.7\overline2$ as an infinite geometric series.

How would I approach this? I can express $0.0\overline2$ as an infinite geometric series $(0.2+0.2+0.002\dots)$, but how can I show the above number as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\;2.7\overline2 = \frac{49}{18}\,$. Find an $x$ such that $\frac{1}{1-x}= \frac{49}{18}\,$.

Comment: So $x$ would be $\frac{49}{31}$, but how did you get that equation?

Comment: @suomynonA:  It is from the sum of a geometric series.  The first term is $1$ and the ratio is $x$

Comment: @suomynonA Which one? The first one is from $10 \cdot 2.7\overline2 - 2.7\overline2 = 24.5\,$ (just as an example of possible derivation among several). The second one is just the sum of a geometric series with ratio $x$ starting at $1\,$. P.S. I think you got that $x$ reversed.

Comment: I see how you did it now, thanks. P.S. Oops, somehow I thought $-49x=-31$ means that $x=\frac{49}{31}$

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it is through breaking it up into infinite sums for 2.222 repeating and 0.5.

So: $$2.2\overline{2} + 0.5=2.7\overline{2}$$

$$2.2\bar2 = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{10^n}$$

$$0.5 = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^n} = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{4 \cdot 2^n}$$

$$2.7\overline{2} = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{10^n} + \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{4 \cdot 2^n} = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{8 + 5^n}{4 \cdot 10^n}$$

Just in case you needed a single infinite sum without any outside parts.

Answer (score 0):

$0.\bar2 = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{10^n}$

That looks like an infinite geometric progression with the ratio of $\dfrac{1}{10}$, right?

Finding the sum of this is similar to a GP,
Sum of a Geomtric Progression(I used it's acronym earlier) for n terms is given by

$S_n = \dfrac{a(1 - r^n)}{1 - r}$

where $S_n$ is the Sum to n terms, a is the first term and r is the common ratio.

For an *infinite number of terms, you could* take the limit. The limit of that converges only if your ratio is less than or equal to one.

In that case $(1-r^n) \approx 1$ as n approaches infinity.
So, the sum becomes

$S_{\infty} = \dfrac{a}{1-r}$

Put your a as $\dfrac{2}{10}$, and ratio as $\dfrac{1}{10}$ to get

$S_{\infty} = \dfrac{2}{9}$

Similarly for $2.7\bar2$ take the 2.7 out side and keep the rest of it as a sum and get an infinite progression like before.